# http load failed with status 416

Tags: javascript, html, video

I create elearning courses, and I'm having a very persistent loading issue with one of the courses I've been working on.

When I run my files through the debugger, this error comes up:
"Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed."

Followed by this error for each .mp4 file in the course:
"HTTP load failed with status 416"

This reflects the problems that we're seeing on the front end - issues with the videos in the course not preloading, and causing blank spaces or causing the entire course to stall.

Does anyone know if these are issues with my html file, or on the server side? Any suggestions?

Here is the link:
http://files.foodallergy.org/video-library/storyline/RecognizingandRespondingtoAnaphylaxis/story_html5.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen that error before on a Storyline file. The error 416 suggests that the media file hasn't downloaded properly before its playback is started. If I return to the course, then the video plays correctly. Storyline does not stream media so it has to download them completely first.

Try delaying the start of the video/sound clip by say 2 seconds on the slide. This should give it enough time to download.

If you don't like the gap, then it could be covered with a fade-in slide transition or similar.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your response. Is there no way to force Storyline to preload content? I didn't create the course, so unfortunately I don't have the leeway to do much editing of the content, I'm only trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Try this suggestion from the articulate website. In HTML5 it should stream MP4, unless it has a problem with the mp4 header.

https://articulate.com/support/article/mp4-movie-doesnt-begin-playing-until-it-has-fully-downloaded

You should be able to unzip the scorm package, apply the fix using the qt-faststart program to the mp4s and then rezip it. When you zip it make sure that you can see the imsmanifest.xml in the folder where you zip it to make it a scorm file again.